# Java not using recompiled imported package

Tags: java

I have a simple case and am a Java beginner. Package "b" import package "a" and works normally. If I make changes to package "a" and recompile package "a" the changes do not show when I call a's functions from package "b". The changes I've made are simply debugging print statements. From package "a" directory, I run:

`javac -cp "/path/to/my.jar" *.java`

Then, I do the same for package "b". I then run package "b" and I see no debug statements at all. What am I doing wrong? I have tried to clean the projects but that doesn't help.

I've updated `my.jar` file with the new compiled package "a":

`jar -uf my.jar /path/to/a.class`

Comment: To be honest the question is not clear at all :(

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really new to Java...first day

Comment: You need to explain exactly what commands you run in which sequence.

Comment: i agree with @tgdavies - if you give a more detailed step instruction, you could get more help!